Solution Laravel Reverb does not work in production with Apache
Description
I'm having problems with Reverb in production (everything works locally) using Apache + lightsail aws + lamp 8.2.
Services:

Reverb Version: @beta
Laravel Version: ^11.0
PHP Version: 8.2

My .env
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb
REVERB_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
REVERB_APP_ID=xxx
REVERB_APP_KEY=xxx
REVERB_APP_SECRET=xxx
REVERB_HOST="mydomain.com"
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

routes/channel.php
Broadcast::channel('update_coins.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
  return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

resources/js/echo.js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'reverb',
  key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
  wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
  wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
  wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
  forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

Vhosts
boost-https-vhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.key"

  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/boost/public"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/boost/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ProxyPass "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
  ProxyPassReverse "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
</VirtualHost>

boost-vhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/boost/public"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/boost/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # ROUTER WWW Redirect.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # ROUTER HTTPS Redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

When I try to run a test command:
$user_id = 1;
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user->update(['coins' => $user->coins + 100]);
UpdateCoinsEvent::dispatch($user);

The following error is thrown:
local.ERROR: Pusher error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Not Found</title>
        {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException(code: 0): Pusher error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">

        <title>Not Found</title>

Steps To Reproduce
protected $signature = 'coins';
protected $description = 'Command description';

public function handle()
{
    $user_id = 1;

    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $user->update(['coins' => $user->coins + 100]);
    UpdateCoinsEvent::dispatch($user);
}

Error
local.ERROR: Pusher error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Not Found</title>
        {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException(code: 0): Pusher error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">

        <title>Not Found</title>

SOLUTION
Take a good look at the settings, follow and you will get the fix!
First thing you will do is create a subdomain (it can be on cloudflare, with the cloud or without the cloud activated.)
Now configure your .env like this:
BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb
REVERB_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
REVERB_APP_ID=your id
REVERB_APP_KEY=your key
REVERB_APP_SECRET=your secret
REVERB_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="ws.example.com"
VITE_REVERB_PORT=443
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https

vhosts subdomain ws-vhost.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ws.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
  ProxyPassReverse "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
</VirtualHost>

vhosts https subdomain ws-https-vhost.conf:
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ws.example.com

  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.key"

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
  ProxyPassReverse "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
</VirtualHost>

After configuring everything, remember to use npm run build and clear the cache, php artisan cache:clear and php artisan route:clear. The reverb.php and broadcasting.php files have not been changed.
Remember that modules and ports need to be activated.
Modules: mod_proxy mod_proxy_wstunnel mod_ssl

check port is enable or not

solution found.

Yes this solutions works, but how can we do it with single domain only ?

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ex_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ex_access.log
</VirtualHost>

Please use the above configuration to work it on the same domain
